# Обработка кнопок если они созданы через цикл for из словаря pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot

```
TOKEN = 'TOKEN '
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["info"])
def get_start_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Hello! I can execute the following commands:\n" + str(bot_help))


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def get_commands_messages(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    key_lowprice = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="/lowprice", callback_data="lowprice")
    key_highprice = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="/highprice", callback_data="highprice")
    key_bestdeal = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="/bestdeal", callback_data="bestdeal")
    key_history = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="/history", callback_data="history")
    keyboard.add(key_lowprice, key_bestdeal, key_highprice, key_history)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "commands:", reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == "lowprice":
        mesg = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Enter the city where you want to search: ')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, low_price_city_request)
    elif call.data == "highprice":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "highprice")
    elif call.data == "bestdeal":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "bestdeal")
    elif call.data == "history":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "history")
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
    

@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, bot_help)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["lowprice"])
def low_price_city_request(message):
    cities_districts = get_city(message.text)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    keys = {}
    for city_name, city_id in cities_districts.items():
        keys[city_id] = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(city_name), callback_data=city_id)
        keyboard.add(keys[city_id])
    mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Make your choice:',  reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, low_price_city_answer)


def low_price_city_answer(call):
    mesg = call.text
    bot.send_message(call.chat.id, mesg)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

не могу понять как обработать и  смогу ли при такой логике свои кнопки,

загвоздка в том что я создаю кнопки text=city_name и callback_data=city_id через список

и наверное тем самым загнал себя в угол, ведь мои кнопки не привязаны к переменным по типу button_1 = ... , button_2 = ...

и т.д.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код в виде текста

Comment: Обработка логики происходит через callback_data в ```@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call)```

Comment: def low_price_city_answer(call) не отрабатывает

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["lowprice"])
def low_price_city_request(message):
    cities_districts = get_city(message.text)
    print("BOT LOG: cities_districts ", cities_districts)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for city_name, city_id in cities_districts.items():
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=city_name,
            callback_data="lowprice_answer" + city_id
        )
        keyboard.add(button)
    mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Make your choice:',  reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, low_price_city_answer)
```

Добавил в `callback_data` строку "lowprice_answer" и добавил `city_id`

```
def low_price_city_answer(message):
    mesg = message.text
    return mesg
```

Отлавливаю сообщение

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == "lowprice":
        mesg = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Enter the city where you want to search: ')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, low_price_city_request)
    elif call.data == "highprice":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "highprice")
    elif call.data == "bestdeal":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "bestdeal")
    elif call.data == "history":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "history")
    elif call.data.startswith("lowprice_answer"):
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, call.data.replace("lowprice_answer", ''))
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
```

И делаю простую логику, если сообщение начинается на строку "lowprice_answer" + `city_id`, откидываю `(call.data.replace("lowprice_answer", '')))` и оставляю чистый `city_id`, который нужен для дальнейшей работы. Можно вывести в чат бота или передать в другую функцию.